# Create dictionary from list python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have many lists in this format:

```
['1', 'O1', '', '', '', '0.0000', '0.0000', '', '']
['2', 'AP', '', '', '', '35.0000', '105.0000', '', '']
['3', 'EU', '', '', '', '47.0000', '8.0000', '', '']
```

I need to create a dictionary with key as the first element in the list and value as the entire list. None of the keys are repeating. 
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put all your lists in another list and do this:

```
my_dict = {}
for list in lists:
  my_dict[list[0]] = list[:]
```

This basically gets the first element and puts it as a key in `my_dict` and put the list as the value.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> lists = [['1', 'O1', '', '', '', '0.0000', '0.0000', '', ''],
['2', 'AP', '', '', '', '35.0000', '105.0000', '', ''],
['3', 'EU', '', '', '', '47.0000', '8.0000', '', '']]
>>> {x[0]: x for x in lists}
{'1': ['1', 'O1', '', '', '', '0.0000', '0.0000', '', ''], '3': ['3', 'EU', '', '', '', '47.0000', '8.0000', '', ''], '2': ['2', 'AP', '', '', '', '35.0000', '105.0000', '', '']}
```

Comment: But what I would do if I need to make a separate dictionary for each list and I don't want to merge the lists?

Comment: @wannabe_geek you have to keep your lists somehow. putting them all in one list is the easiest way. you can use other things like linked list if you want. your output follows the same rule. You have to keep it somewhere. Dictionary is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

If your indexes are sequential integers, you may use a list instead of a dict:

```
lst = [None]+[x[1:] for x in sorted(lists)]
```

use it only if it *really* fits your problem, though.